# How can stop receiving data from Bluetooth without Loss the Previous data?

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino, bluetooth

I want to receive sensor data from Arduino with HC-05 Bluetooth  module in Kotlin.
I have a **receiveData** function and when I clicking on the start button , **receiveData** is called and data show on the text view ;
This is working correctly.
But I want to *stop receive data* when I clicking on the Stop button and **keep** that Previous data on my text view , but I don't have any idea for the stop button.
This is my *start monitoring button* setOnClickListener:

```
btn_startMonitoring.setOnClickListener { receiveData() }
```

My **receiveData** function is this :

```
    private fun receiveData() {

         val handler = Handler()  
         var stopWorker = false
         var readMessage = ""
         val buffer = ByteArray(1024)

         val workerThread = Thread {
             while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted && !stopWorker) {
                 try {
                     val bytes = m_bluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(buffer)
                     if (bytes > 0) {
                         readMessage += String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                         handler.post {
                             mTxtReceive!!.append(readMessage)
                             scrollView.post(Runnable
                             { scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) })
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         Toast.makeText(this , "bytes is less than zero" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                     }
                 } catch (ex: IOException) {
                     stopWorker = true

                 }
             }
         }
         workerThread.start()
        
     }
```